# Error: External ID and Unique field limit exceeded

Tags: custom-field, person-accounts

I am getting this Error in Contact Object(Person Account Activated) for the Number Datatype field Which I am selecting  has Unique. when I googled it I get to know that only 3 Field can be made it has a Unique, but  I want 4th field also.[image]

Comment: This is a black tab limit so Salesforce support can increase it for you.  The hard limit is 5 I believe.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 way - either ask salesforce to raise your organization limit (I believe they do that for top clients ) or create custom logic in trigger which will check if value in this field is unique in your system.

Creating such logic should not be a problem. it should be enough to use SOQL query and addError() method, If it has to be case sensitive it could take more work.

Here is some method that you can use in after Insert and Update trigger actions

```
public static void chcekUniqueFields(Map<Id, Contact> newContacts){

Set<String> uniqeValues = new Set<String>();
for(Contact con : newContacts.values()){
    uniqeValues.add(con.Your_Field__c);    
}

Contact[] contactsFrmDB = [SELECT Id FROM Contat WHERE Your_Field__c IN : uniqeValues];

if(contactsFrmDB.isEmpty()){
    return;
}

for(Contact con : contactsFrmDB){
    if(newContacts.get(con.Id) == null){
        newContacts.get(con.Id).addError('Error Message');
    }    
}


}
```

To make it case sensitive you have to create separate method. I also skiped check if there is duplicate in newContacts Map - if you will need it just ask :)